# C# Trying to decode websocket (wss) frames

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, decoding

I have a c# application which is connecting to a javascript web socket using websocketsharp (probably a  node.js websocket server).

I can blindly send data and get responses by copying hex data via chrome devtools after converting it to a byte array.

The problem starts here. I'm trying to decode the response but no luck yet. Tried a lot of examples and functions around the web.

When simply using **Encoding.UTF8.GetString** result is half readable (for example: i can see nicknames) and messy with a lot of unknown characters.. And already tried other character sets. (Ascii / unicode / utf32 etc...)

When i use **int len = bytes[offset + 1] - 0x80;** the result is always -126 so i can't even get to the length / mask part.

Probably didn't understand the logic or I'm skipping a simple part.

Sorry for my english, any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Return data is Uint8Array
Edit: Socket is an HTML5Websocket